# Is parachain a data structure?

Tags: polkadot, parachain, blockchain, documentation

In Polkadot docs, Parachain is defined as:

> A parachain is an application-specific data structure that is globally
> coherent and can be validated by the validators of the Relay Chain.

Why have they used the term data structure instead of chain?
links to [doc](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-parachains)

Answer (score 2):

A blockchain is a datastructure essentially. It's a distributed linked-list that uses a consensus mechanism to append blocks and grow the list. A parachain is a blockchain, hence the term makes perfect sense in this case.

Comment: can you please provide me with some links where i can further understand it